# X Y coordinates from Plain Bitmap in Line-Styled Bitmap

Tags: math, bitmap, coordinates

Let try to explain my problem (Sorry, if my English isn't correct):
I have a programm which draws a picture from a plain bitmap.
For Example:

```
 101
 000
 111

  \/

[]  []

[][][]
```

Now I want to make my Bitmap a little different.
Like this:

```
       1
       0
       1
101    0
000 -> 0
111    0
       1
       1
       1
```

But if I want to do this, I can't use X,Y coordinates like in the Plain Bitmap.
Is there a way to calculate the line only with X,Y coordinates?
Big Thanks,
   Skayo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If numbering is zero-based, then every (X,Y) pair gives new coordinate

```
NewY = X + Y * Width
```

Comment: Length of matrix line (3 in your case)